# Generating a Monotonically Decreasing Sequence that adds to 1 for any length

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

I would like to generate a monotonically decreasing sequence whose elements will add to one, and generate this sequence for any order $L$. For instance, if $L=2$, then $\vec{s} = [ \frac{3}{4}, \frac{1}{4}]$ will work. I have generated a few more by inspection this way, but I imagine that there might be a sequence already discovered that does this.

Am I correct in this assumption? Or will I have to do something numerically? If so, any ideas on such an algorithm?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to impose some degree of randomness to the output?

Answer (score 2):

Since $1+2+3+ \ldots +n=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, you might consider

$$
\frac{n}{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}, \frac{n-1}{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}},
\ldots, \frac{1}{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Extending your thought in the question, for a length $L$ sequence to sum to $1$, you can consider 
$$
\frac{2L-1}{L^2},...,\frac{3}{L^2},\frac{1}{L^2}.
$$
because 
$$
1+3+..+2L-1=\frac{2L-1+1}{2}\cdot L=L^2
$$
For example, when $L=2$, you get $\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

For odd $L$ you can start from $L,L-1,L-2\ldots ,1,0,-1,-2 \ldots -L$, which sums to $0$ and add $\frac 1L$ to each term.  For even $L$ just delete the zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can take any long enough secuence of increasing non-negative numbers $\langle a_k \rangle$, and do:
$$
s_k = \frac{a_{L - k + 1}}{\sum_{1 \le j \le L} a_j}
$$
Selecting the $a_k$ appropiately, you can tweak your sequence at will